# Python: join dataframes and filter rows by condition

Tags: python, pandas

I would appreciate some help on this: I've merged two tables with this structure and I'd need to get the list of items with different LOCNAME in both tables

Input:

[image]

Expected list output:
[image]

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

Madrid1 = pd.read_csv('Madrid1.csv')
Madrid2 = pd.read_csv('Madrid2.csv')

merged = pd.merge(Madrid1, Madrid2, how='inner', left_on='LocID', right_on='LocID').head(1)
filter = Madrid1['LocName_'] != (Madrid2['LocName_']) # THIS IS NOT CORRECT!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of items with different LOCNAME in both tables, you can use the loc function in Pandas with a condition that checks for the inequality between the LocName_ column in Madrid1 and Madrid2. Here's the modified code:

```
import pandas as pd

Madrid1 = pd.read_csv('Madrid1.csv')
Madrid2 = pd.read_csv('Madrid2.csv')

merged = pd.merge(Madrid1, Madrid2, how='inner', left_on='LocID', right_on='LocID')
filtered = merged.loc[merged['LocName__x'] != merged['LocName__y'], 'LocID':'LocName__x']
```

The merged DataFrame contains all the rows that have matching LocID in both tables. The loc function then selects only the rows where the LocName__x column (from Madrid1) is not equal to the LocName__y column (from Madrid2). Finally, the result contains only the LocID and LocName__x columns (from Madrid1).

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! Can I ask you one more question, how can the output show more columns, I would like to show the list for columns LOCID, LocName__x and LocName__y

Comment: To show the LocID, LocName__x, and LocName__y columns in the output, you can modify the last line of code to: filtered = merged.loc[merged['LocName__x'] != merged['LocName__y'], ['LocID', 'LocName__x', 'LocName__y']]     This will select the three columns specified in the list and return them in the filtered DataFrame.